# KDE keep warning "No External Display" all the time

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma, external-monitor

I'm currently using KDE Plasma. But, since I installed it, every time when turning my computer on it shows a popup warning that there is "No External Display", its very annoying because it keeps showing that message all the time. Anyone know how could I solve this? or at least force it to never show this popup again.

Versions: Kubuntu 18.04, KDE Plasma 5.12.8

Comment: What version of Kubuntu? What version of Plasma?

Comment: Kubuntu 18.04, KDE Plasma 5.12.8

Comment: I could only find [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/5svri8/no_external_display_keeps_popping_up_on_screen/). And one suggestion there is to turn off the OSD: System Settings > Workspace > Desktop Behavior > Workspace > turn off "Display visual feedback for status changes". If you do so, you'll also not see the volume increase/decrease pop-up but actual notifications will be unaffected.